# NGINX configuration for website and nodejs application

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm try to setup my NGINX server for both a website and a nodejs application.
I have two subdomains pointing correctly to my server, both to the same IP.

`one.mydomain.com (main site) --> 123.456.789`
`two.mydomain.com (NODE App)  --> 123.456.789`

I've already setup my website and my nodejs app, so I can reach both of them.

My default configuration is

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

my one.mysite.com configuration is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/one.mysite.com;
        index index.html;
        server_name one.mysite.com;
        location / {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }
}
```

and my two.mysite.com (the node app) is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        root /var/www/html/two.mysite.com;
        index index.html;
        server_name two.mysite.com;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

The problem is that given that the NODE application is listening on port `8080`, I'm not able to figure out how to avoid visiting `one.mydomain.com:8080` and reach the NODE js app.

How can I reach this? Is there a way to tell NGINX to block visiting `one.mydomain.com` on port `8080`?

Thanks

Comment: could you show us your server block configuration ?

Comment: of course, I've updated my question

Comment: Looks like your Node app is also listening on 80, and not on 8080?

Comment: Are you sure that both configs are even enabled? I think you should get an error when you run `nginx -t` if you have two servers listening on the same port.